# Process is not triggered after field update from approval process

Tags: process-builder, approval-process

I have an approval process that sets a "isApproved" boolean field to True in an object. I have a process builder that is configured (with record creation and update) with entry criteria that executes only if the "isApproved" is True.

However, when I create a new object with default false "isApproved" and go through the approval process, the process is not fired.
But when I change the boolean value manually, the process is fired (which means the process is working fine).

Why isn't the process fired with the field update from approval process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not checked re-evaluate workflow.
please check this link this might help you

http://www.shelovestocode.com/2018/10/process-builder-is-not-fired-when-field.html

Comment: Hello,
I think you have not checked re-evaluate workflow.
please check this link this might help you

http://www.shelovestocode.com/2018/10/process-builder-is-not-fired-when-field.html

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.